# Angular Pipe and Map are getting called again from a different function

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a table where I display a list of assets which are stored in an Observable.
For each asset, there is a delete button that deletes the asset from the table.
I also have a drop-down where the user can add assets to the table (the assets deleted from table reappear in the drop-down too).
[image]

The following is the delete function that simply filters the Observable (assets$), and add the deleted asset into the drop-down list, I also have other lists (assetsToDelete and assetsToAdd for adding to the database).

```
 onDelete(a: any) {
    const form: any = {
        assetId: a.id,
        scenarioId: this.data.id,
    };
    this.assets$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    this.assets$ = this.assets$.pipe(
        map((asset: any) => {
            console.log(asset);
            const assets = asset.filter((assett: any) => assett.id !== a.id);
            return assets;
        })
    );
    // this.assets$.subscribe(data => {
    //     return data.filter((assett: any) => assett.id !== a.id);
    // })
    this.assets$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    this.dropdownList = this.dropdownList.concat([a]);
    this.assetsToDelete.push(form);
    this.assetsToAdd = this.assetsToAdd.filter((id: any) => id !== a.id);
}
```

My Add function is triggered when the user presses on the "Add Selected Assets" button:

```
    addAssetsToScenario() {
    this.edit = true;
    if (this.selectedItems.length === 0) {
        Swal.fire('No Assets', 'Please select asset(s) to add', 'warning');
    } else {
        const ids: any = this.selectedItems.map(curr => (curr as any).id);
        this.assetsToAdd.push.apply(this.assetsToAdd, ids);
        this.assets$ = this.assets$.pipe(
            map((assets: any) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                    assets.push(this.selectedItems[i]);
                    this.dropdownList = this.dropdownList.filter(
                        asset => asset.id !== (this.selectedItems[i] as any).id
                    );
                    this.assetsToDelete = this.assetsToDelete.filter(
                        (asset: { assetId: any }) => {
                            return asset.assetId !== (this.selectedItems[i] as any).id;
                        }
                    );
                }
                this.selectedItems = [];
                return assets;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting all of the selected items in the drop-down and pushing them into the Observable (assets$).
There are some other functions to filter the drop-down and the assetsToDelete lists.

My problem is that whenever I delete one of the assets it gets deleted successfully. However, when I then try to add any asset from the drop down menu, nothing happens.
I tried to track the issue and it seems that the pipe(map()...) in the "onDelete" function is being called whenever I try to use it again in any function such as the "addAssetsToScenario" function.

I am not sure why this is happening, as I am not calling the onDelete function when adding the assets.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

> this.assets$ = this.assets$.pipe(...)

you are chaining observables. You are piping the output of the existing `$asset` observable to a new observable and storing the new observable in `assets$`. So when:

1. You call `onDelete` you are piping the output of the existing `assets$` observable to a new observable that you put into `assets$`.
2. You call `addAssetsToScenario` you chain another new observable that takes the output of the existing `assets$` observable created in step 1 and again storing this new observable in `assets$`.
3. subscribing to `assets$` after step 2 will pipe the original observable to the map operator created in step 1 and then pipe the output of that to the map operator created in step 2.

So yes, the map from `onDelete` will be called along with the map from `addAssetsToScenario` depending on when you have subscribed to `assets$`. If you call these functions multiple times you will keep adding observables to the chain.

I suggest you look for a tutorial on rxjs to get a better understanding of observables, subscriptions and operators.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this.assets$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));` doesn't just print the array, it calls every operation you piped to it so far. The bellow code is an infinite loop.

```html
function removeElement() {
  assetsObservable = assetsObservable.pipe(
    map((asset: any[]) => {
      assetsObservable.subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
      return asset.filter((e) => e < 4);
    })
  );
}

removeElement();

assetsObservable.subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
```